# Assigning QTcpSocket object

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I have a class with `QTcpSocket socket;` as private member. Then, in class constructor I'm initialising with `socket = new QTcpSocket();`

When compiling, I'm getting error:
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::socket = (operator new(16u), (<statement>, ((QTcpSocket*)<anonymous>)))’`

What's wrong?

Comment: are you sure  `QTcpObject` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check declaration: if you wrote `QTcpSocket socket;` you declare a object not a pointer. In this case you can t construct it with `new`.

You should declare `QTcpSocket* socket;`